# How to avoid empty DOM elements in code?

Tags: d3.js

How can I avoid the creation of empty elements in the SVG code?
In a graph drawn with d3, I would like only specific nodes to a circle and other to only have text.

```
    svg.append("circle").filter(function(d) { return d.hasLabel; })
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.x) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) });
```

It works somehow, only nodes where hasLabel is true show a circle, but looking at the HTML page source code I see that nodes where hasLabel is false have . Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the `append` to after the `filter`, like so..

```
svg.filter(function(d) { return d.hasLabel; })
    .append("circle") 
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.x) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) });
```